# Slack export from web api

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a free plan on slack and, for a bunch of reasons, I regularly download the export zip file from the webpage https://www.slack.com/services/export.

Is there a way to export exactly that .zip file through web api? I'll use it from a python script.

I cannot find anything inside the documentation. So I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single API method for this function, but the same information can be gathered pretty easily combining several existing API methods:

- [`channels.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list) - to get the list of all channels
- [`channels.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) - to get all messages for a channel
- [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) - list of all users

And by using the alternative [conversations API](https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api) you can even get all messages from private channels, which the export function can not do.

Comment: Thank you Erik. I've used those methods, but I'm using a python application (slack-export-viewer) that requires the json exactly how they are exported with the web interface.

Comment: You may want to take a closer look at the data from those API methods. I might be wrong, but at first glance it looks like there provide the exact same output like the official export.

Comment: Oh ok, maybe I'm wrong. I'll look at it better. Thanks a lot!